# Entity Framework support in MonoTouch and Mono for Android

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Now that the upcoming Mono version includes EF4, are the imminent plans to include it in MonoTouch and Mono for Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Android, the chances that we include it are very high, as Android can run the entire CLR.  On iOS the situation is more complicated, as there are various [limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations) imposed by the iOS kernel that prevent some forms of generics code from running.

Additionally, all of the EF work runs on top of Mono 2.11, while both mobile products are based on a much older codebase, so any upgrade will have to wait until both products are rebased on top of the upcoming Mono 2.12, and that wont happen until December or so.

Comment: Thanks Miguel.  Any suggestions for currently available alternatives?  For my current project, a lightweight solution will do, and of course minimal integration would be nice...

Comment: I've used both Catnap ORM (https://github.com/timscott/catnap) and sqlite-net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Both are good, each with its own limitations.

Comment: OpenNETCF's ORM runs under Mono (forAndroid and Touch), Compact Framework, Windows Phone and Windows Desktop, framework 3.5 or later, supporting SQLite and/orSQLCE where available  http://orm.codeplex.com

Comment: Hey, so OpenNETCF just blew my mind. I'd like to do more research on it as I've been doing comparative analysis of approaches. If you make it an answer I will upvote so you get some cred=)

Comment: @ctacke I really really want to hear more about the "trivial" monotouch port for SQLLite!

Comment: Well it works for Mon for Android, and our experience so far is that the M4A->MonoTouch migration tends to be rather smooth, so it's probably just a matter of creating the MT projects.  We've implemented ORM under desktop framework, Compact Framework and M4A using SQL Compact, SQLite and Azure so the code itself is pretty portable to begin with.  I just haven't had the time or specific need to move it to MT yet.