# EntityFramework available in mono for android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

[Entity Framework support in MonoTouch and Mono for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025819/entity-framework-support-in-monotouch-and-mono-for-android)

As per the above link entity framework should be available by this time. But I have downloaded xamarin for visual studio recently and trying to build a application which uses entiry framework. But I am getting a compilation error

```
The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have set the reference to System.Data, but looks like still it doesn't find Entity.

Mono.Android is properties shows the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v3.1\Mono.Android.dll
```

Earlier it was referring v1, I changed it assuming that newer version might have implemented it.

Also, I don't find System.Data.dll in V3 so its still linking to V1.

1. Is it that EF still not implemented for mono android?
2. If not implemented yet, EF is open source, is will I be able to just compile it for monodroid?
3. Is there any alternative to EF since my code uses DbContext, DBSet etc. If not how can I port this?

Comment: 1. EF not ported to android yet. Looks like no plan to implement for android.

Answer (score 0):

Though EF is not supported currently, maybe the best approach would be to create a Web API with your current EF contexts as your data store? You can then implement the API as a service in a PCL and reference it to your monodroid project. You'd then deserialize the objects from the JSON/XML responses and do whatever you need with it.

Here's an example of what a service might look like: 
https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ServiceSamples/StockService/StockService.cs

You also have the option of using a "EF-like" local database ([SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)), however it will all be stored in a .sqlite file on the phone itself instead of a central server.